# How common are squat marks on shoulders?

Tags: squats

I have recently gotten back into squatting and rediscovered something that would happen whenever I squat. For context I was free squatting 185lbs at five sets of six reps

Referencing the attached similar post [Strange mark on shoulders after squatting](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7719/39657)
I found I had slightly similar marks but mine were wider and further down my back making me think it was not completely because it was fully forward. Like was mentioned. I was also using a free squat bar and not a smith machine.

My first thought is that this could due to the shirt I was wearing? 100% Cotton and a stitched shoulder seam

I am wondering if others have experienced similar occurences?

Reference photos here 36 hours after squatting:
[image: downwards angle of twin shoulder marks]

[image: front angle of one shoulder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There's all sorts of marks and bruises that you can get in the gym; particularly from barbells. Strange marks on your back from squatting is one of them. In this case it looks like the skin pinched when the bar rolled and broke some capillaries. It could also be caused by the bar's knurling pressing down so much. It's just a bruise and should go away.

Other kinds of bruises you can expects are:

- Bruises on shins from deadlifts
- Loss of hair on shins from deadlifts
- Bruises on stomach from a weighlifting belt
- Bruises on hips from hip thrusts
- Thick calluses on hands
- Mysterious bruises that somehow appear and you don't remember why

It's not something to worry about. It's just a symptom of an active lifestyle.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response DeeV! Glad to know I'm not, observably, doing something wrong.